# extracting int into array from long long in c

Tags: c, arrays, int, long-integer

I'm new to programming and have no experience with arrays of undefined length.
I want to extract specific numbers from a long long that is generated by user input (because I failed to do so with a char).
The best result would be for me that it would end up in an array with each digit its own int so that i can run loops and do math with them.

Say that i want to get the 20th digit from the right, with the amount of digits that the user put in GetLongLong unknown, this is what my code looks like:

```
int spec20 = (digits / 10000000000000000000) % 10;
```

How can I make this simpler and use an array to store specific digits?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
char str[100]; // your number should most probably fit
sprintf(str,"%lld",digits);
```

then `str` will contain string representation of your number, and you can find 20th element from the right (starting to count from 1) like this (not the only way for sure).

```
int d_len = strlen(str);
int the_20th_pos = (d_len>20? d_len-20: -1); // take care of numbers less than 20 digits
int the_20th = (int)(the_20th_pos<0? 0: str[d_len-the_20th_pos]-'0');
```